# Make target depend on multiple files in its subdirectory

Tags: makefile, eval, wildcard

I have several modules I would like to compile, lets say `foo` and `bar`.

```
$MODULES = foo bar
```

They each are in a separate subdirectory with the same name (e.g. `source/foo/foo.o`), so my object files are:

```
$MODULE_OBJ := $(foreach module, $(MODULES), source/$(module)/$(module).o)
```

Now, I would like to write a generic rule for both modules, so that they depend on all the source files of their subdirectory (e.g. `source/foo/*.f90`), but only the one named just like the module is needed to compile it (e.g. `$(FC) -c source/foo/foo.f90` is the recipe). I've read that this is commonly solved using `eval` and `call`. This doesn't work for me; I've tried to output the prerequisites for debugging, but no luck. Here is what I've tried:

```
define modulerule
$(1): $$(dir $(1))*.f90
    $$(info prereq = $$^)
    $$(FC) -c $$(basename $$@).f90
endef

$(foreach obj, %(MODULE_OBJ), $(eval $(call modulerule, $(obj))))
```

Comment: Why not simplify things, by having a toplevel makefile that then calls make recursively in each module directory? Then in the module directory you can have a makefile specific to that module.

Comment: @TimothyBrown Recursive Make is a very bad idea, it does not work, Make was not designed for that.  Amen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on what you have, one way of defining a generic rule would be

```
MODULES = foo bar
MODULE_OBJS := $(foreach module, $(MODULES), source/$(module)/$(module).o)

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(MODULE_OBJS): $$(wildcard $$(dir $$@)*.f90)
    $(FC) -c $(basename $@).f90  -o $@
```